# pdf.js turn.js kDefaultURL doesn't open

Tags: turnjs, pdf.js

I use pdfjs turnjs of http://www.maxims6n.bget.ru/book2/viewer/viewer.html and my kDefaultURL does not open. But, if I use the open file button, it's works.

thank's

Comment: You can check there are more then one JS error display via console of browser, Please fix it first. May be these errors are issue here.

Comment: i have this error "  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."